# Kohana Development Cycle

Tags: kohana, php

I was wondering if users that are using Kohana primarily to explain how they go from planing to deployment in Kohana. Why do you use Kohana instead of the other frameworks that you tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a base setup that I continually refine that includes all the basic stuff that I need for my projects.  The cascading file system that Kohana uses makes this very simple.  You can see something similar at http://github.com/synapsestudios/kohana-projecttemplate.

I converted from CI and stayed because everything felt simpler using PHP5 OOP concepts the way they should be.  Plus the ORM helped me get models set up very quickly.

Comment: quick question, Is this a K3 or a K2 project?